# Simple C Program To Convert Two Digits Into Words

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is to write a program wherein you input two digits and 
then they are converted into words which gets printed. The problem is that this program 
hangs after you input the two digits and I have no idea why. Any and all help is appreciated.
I am a beginner and all I can use to solve this is basically if and switch. Thanks again.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int firstNum, secondNum;

    printf("Enter a two digit number: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &firstNum,&secondNum);

    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 0){
            printf("You entered the number ten\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 1){
                printf("You entered the number eleven\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 2){
                printf("You entered the number twelve\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 3){
                printf("You entered the number thirteen\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 4){
                printf("You entered the number forteen\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 5){
                printf("You entered the number fifteen\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 6){
                printf("You entered the number sixteen\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 7){
                printf("You entered the number seventeen\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 8){
                printf("You entered the number eighteen\n");}
    if (firstNum == 1 && secondNum == 9){
                printf("You entered the number nineteen\n");}
    switch(firstNum){
        case 2: printf("You entered the number twenty-");break;
        case 3: printf("You entered the number thirty-");break;
        case 4: printf("You entered the number forty-");break;
        case 5: printf("You entered the number fifty-");break;
        case 6: printf("You entered the number sixty-");break;
        case 7: printf("You entered the number seventy-");break;
        case 8: printf("You entered the number eighty-");break;
        case 9: printf("You entered the number ninty-");break;
    }
    switch (secondNum){
        case 1: printf("one.\n");break;
        case 2: printf("two.\n");break;
        case 3: printf("three.\n");break;
        case 4: printf("four.\n");break;
        case 5: printf("five.\n");break;
        case 6: printf("six.\n");break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How exactly does it hand? Do you get a segmentation fault (access violation)?

Comment: Also, note that `%d` reads a whole number, not just 1 digit. If you want to read two numbers they should be space-separated and you should use `"%d %d"` (with space). If you want to read two digits, you should read with `scanf("%c%c", &digit1, &digit2);` (digits are `char`) and then convert them to number: `firstNum = digit1 - '0';`

Comment: Why not use `scanf("%d" &num);` and then check that it's two digits (i.e. `num > 0 && num < 100`)? Then use division and modulo for values of ten and less or 20 and higher.

Comment: I get it... I see what I was doing wrong... d could itself be a two-digit num thus it was waiting for the second number LOL wow thanks guys. I really appreciate the help. Sometime the most obvious things are the hardest to see!

Comment: soulrain, I notice you have not yet voted on any answers. Did you know that you can show your appreciation by upvoting any post that you find helpful? (click the arrow symbol on top of post score)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program "hangs" because it is waiting for a second number.

Instead of <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>, type <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

---

You need to verify the return value from `scanf()`

```
if (scanf("%d%d", &firstNum, &secondNum) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops, the scanf didn't read 2 numbers.\n");
} else {
    /* continue with program */
    /* you might as well see what scanf got from the input */
    printf("scanf got the values %d and %d.\n", firstNum, secondNum);
}
```

Comment: That can't make _his_ program hang. The problem should be somewhere else, although it is a good point.

Comment: Thanks @Shahbaz, answer edited to include a solution for what I think is the real reason it "hangs".

Comment: haha, right! I was thinking by "hangs" he means something terrible. Didn't think of "blocked on I/O"

Comment: wow tons of stuff to read through already.... which I am doing right now. Very new so trying to figure out what the responses mean exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**A very simple code (Specially for beginners).**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
int num,n,r;

printf("Enter a two-digit number: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

n = num/10;
r = num%10;

switch(n)
{
    case 1: switch(r)
            {
                case 0: printf("Ten");
                        break;   
                case 1: printf("Eleven");
                        break;
                case 2: printf("Twelve");
                        break;
                case 3: printf("Thirteen");
                        break;
                case 4: printf("Fourteen");
                        break;
                case 5: printf("Fifteen");
                        break;
                case 6: printf("Sixteen");
                        break;
                case 7: printf("Seventeen");
                        break;
                case 8: printf("Eighteen");
                        break;
                case 9: printf("Nineteen");
            }
            break;                                    
    case 2: printf("Twenty-");
            break;
    case 3: printf("Thirty-");
            break;
    case 4: printf("Fourty-");
            break;
    case 5: printf("Fifty-");
            break;
    case 6: printf("Sixty-");
            break;
    case 7: printf("Seventy-");
            break;
    case 8: printf("Eighty-");
            break;
    case 9: printf("Ninety-");
            break;
}
if(n != 1)
{
     switch(r)
     {
         case 1: printf("one");
                 break;
         case 2: printf("two");
                 break;
         case 3: printf("three");
                 break;
         case 4: printf("four");
                 break;
         case 5: printf("five");
                 break;
         case 6: printf("six");
                 break;
         case 7: printf("seven");
                 break;
         case 8: printf("eight");
                 break;
         case 9: printf("nine");
                 break;
         default: ;                         

         }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program reads data from the console and the console is in "cooked" mode. In this mode, the console collects the input and allows the user to edit it. Data is sent to the program after you press <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The mode you want is "raw" mode. There are various ways to enter raw mode but that depends on your OS.

The quick fix is to enter the two digits and press <kbd>Return</kbd>