# Converting two digit number to words using switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

The question says to write a program asking the user to enter 2 digit number, then prints the English word for it. Suppose you enter '41' the printf function prints out 'forty one'. I have almost completed the program but stuck on converting 11-19 digits into their corresponding words. I used one switch statement to print the first digit and second switch statement to print the second digit. Have a look at the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int first_digit, second_digit;

    printf("Enter two digits: ");
    scanf("%1d%1d",&first_digit,&second_digit);

    switch(first_digit % 10) {
    case 1: printf("ten"); break;
    case 2: printf("twenty"); break;
    case 3: printf("thirty"); break;
    case 4: printf("forty"); break;
    case 5: printf("fifty"); break;
    case 6: printf("sixty"); break;
    case 7: printf("seventy"); break;
    case 8: printf("eighty"); break;
    case 9: printf("ninety"); break;
    }
    switch(second_digit % 10) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: printf(" one"); break;
    case 2: printf(" two"); break;
    case 3: printf(" three"); break;
    case 4: printf(" four"); break;
    case 5: printf(" five"); break;
    case 6: printf(" six"); break;
    case 7: printf(" seven"); break;
    case 8: printf(" eight"); break;
    case 9: printf(" nine"); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also note what happens for input 01

Comment: You have to treat them as a special case. You could for example add another switch-case block.

Comment: Why are you scanning into different variables when you could use `val/10` and `val%10` (or a generalised case) to get digits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple C Program To Convert Two Digits Into Words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940177/simple-c-program-to-convert-two-digits-into-words)

Comment: @sapi I didn't notice your comment, this is fist problem, but notice  OP is using `%1d`

Comment: You are missing a hyphen for "twenty-one", etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Cardinal_numbers

Comment: What Raymond Chen said, also looks like duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732783/error-with-converting-numbers-to-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick and Dirty

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int first_digit, second_digit;

    printf("Enter two digits: ");
    scanf("%1d%1d",&first_digit,&second_digit);

    if (first_digit == 1) {
        switch(second_digit % 10) {
            case 0: printf(" ten"); break;
            case 1: printf(" eleven"); break;
            case 2: printf(" twelve"); break;
            case 3: printf(" thirteen"); break;
            case 4: printf(" fourteen"); break;
            case 5: printf(" fifteen"); break;
            case 6: printf(" sixteen"); break;
            case 7: printf(" seventeen"); break;
            case 8: printf(" eighteen"); break;
            case 9: printf(" ninteen"); break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    switch(first_digit % 10) {
        case 1: printf("ten"); break;
        case 2: printf("twenty"); break;
        case 3: printf("thirty"); break;
        case 4: printf("forty"); break;
        case 5: printf("fifty"); break;
        case 6: printf("sixty"); break;
        case 7: printf("seventy"); break;
        case 8: printf("eighty"); break;
        case 9: printf("ninety"); break;
    }
    switch(second_digit % 10) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: printf(" one"); break;
        case 2: printf(" two"); break;
        case 3: printf(" three"); break;
        case 4: printf(" four"); break;
        case 5: printf(" five"); break;
        case 6: printf(" six"); break;
        case 7: printf(" seven"); break;
        case 8: printf(" eight"); break;
        case 9: printf(" nine"); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your code and modified it with my code and now it works. This was definitely a tricky part. Putting the first digit equal to 1 and then switching the second digit to find the 11-19 digits never occurred to me. Especially the part where you can use switch statement inside an if statement. Now thats clever.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a two digit number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num>10 && num<20){
    badnums(num);
    }
    else{
    goodnums(num);
    }
    return 0;
}

void goodnums(int num){
switch(num % 10) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: printf("ten"); break;
        case 2: printf("twenty"); break;
        case 3: printf("thirty"); break;
        case 4: printf("forty"); break;
        case 5: printf("fifty"); break;
        case 6: printf("sixty"); break;
        case 7: printf("seventy"); break;
        case 8: printf("eighty"); break;
        case 9: printf("ninety"); break;
       }
        switch(num / 10) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: printf(" one"); break;
        case 2: printf(" two"); break;
        case 3: printf(" three"); break;
        case 4: printf(" four"); break;
        case 5: printf(" five"); break;
        case 6: printf(" six"); break;
        case 7: printf(" seven"); break;
        case 8: printf(" eight"); break;
        case 9: printf(" nine"); break;
    }
}

void badnums(int num){
//handle the numbers here 11-19
}
```

Comment: Why 11-19 would be "bad nums" ?

Comment: just a descriptive form to state they are causing a hard to handle situation for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

@user2409559 , @Dinever;
First,no need of % in ur code as u are taking input as first and second digits.
Second your code is incomplete. Enter a number between 10 to 19 and see the output.

I am posting my code below.......take a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int num,n,r;
    
    printf("Enter a two-digit number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    
    n = num/10;
    r = num%10;

    switch(n){
        case 1: switch(r){
            case 0: printf("Ten");
                break;
            case 1: printf("Eleven");
                break;
            case 2: printf("Twelve");
                break;
            case 3: printf("Thirteen");
                break;
            case 4: printf("Fourteen");
                break;
            case 5: printf("Fifteen");
                break;
            case 6: printf("Sixteen");
                break;
            case 7: printf("Seventeen");
                break;
            case 8: printf("Eighteen");
                break;
            case 9: printf("Nineteen");
        }
            break;
        case 2: printf("Twenty-");
            break;
        case 3: printf("Thirty-");
            break;
        case 4: printf("Fourty-");
            break;
        case 5: printf("Fifty-");
            break;
        case 6: printf("Sixty-");
            break;
        case 7: printf("Seventy-");
            break;
        case 8: printf("Eighty-");
            break;
        case 9: printf("Ninety-");
            break;
    }
    if(n != 1){
        switch(r){
            case 1: printf("one");
                break;
            case 2: printf("two");
                break;
            case 3: printf("three");
                break;
            case 4: printf("four");
                break;
            case 5: printf("five");
                break;
            case 6: printf("six");
                break;
            case 7: printf("seven");
                break;
            case 8: printf("eight");
                break;
            case 9: printf("nine");
                break;
            default: ;
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[0] [ishpeck@yoshimitsu digit]$ cat main.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void teens(int number) 
{
    switch(number) 
    {
        case 11: printf("eleven"); break;
        case 12: printf("twelve"); break;
        case 13: printf("thirteen"); break;
        case 14: printf("fourteen"); break;
        case 15: printf("fifteen"); break;
        case 16: printf("sixteen"); break;
        case 17: printf("seventeen"); break;
        case 18: printf("eighteen"); break;
        case 19: printf("nineteen"); break;
        default: printf("ten");
    }
}

void donums(int number) 
{
    switch(number/10) 
    {
        case 1: return teens(number);
        case 2: printf("twenty"); break;
        case 3: printf("thirt"); break;
        case 4: printf("fourt"); break;
        case 5: printf("fift"); break;
        case 6: printf("sixt"); break;
        case 7: printf("sevent"); break;
        case 8: printf("eighty"); break;
        case 9: printf("ninety"); break;
    }
    switch(number%10)
    {
        case 1: printf(" one"); break;
        case 2: printf(" two"); break;
        case 3: printf(" three"); break;
        case 4: printf(" four"); break;
        case 5: printf(" five"); break;
        case 6: printf(" six"); break;
        case 7: printf(" seven"); break;
        case 8: printf(" eight"); break;
        case 9: printf(" nine"); break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int number;
    printf("Enter two digit number.\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    donums(number);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
[0] [ishpeck@yoshimitsu digit]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[0] [ishpeck@yoshimitsu digit]$ gcc -o digits main.c
[0] [ishpeck@yoshimitsu digit]$ for x in {10..99}; do echo $x | ./digits; done
Enter two digit number.
ten
Enter two digit number.
eleven
Enter two digit number.
twelve
Enter two digit number.
thirteen
Enter two digit number.
fourteen
Enter two digit number.
fifteen
Enter two digit number.
sixteen
Enter two digit number.
seventeen
Enter two digit number.
eighteen
Enter two digit number.
nineteen
Enter two digit number.
twenty
Enter two digit number.
twenty one
Enter two digit number.
twenty two
Enter two digit number.
twenty three
Enter two digit number.
twenty four
Enter two digit number.
twenty five
Enter two digit number.
twenty six
Enter two digit number.
twenty seven
Enter two digit number.
twenty eight
Enter two digit number.
twenty nine
Enter two digit number.
thirt
Enter two digit number.
thirt one
Enter two digit number.
thirt two
Enter two digit number.
thirt three
Enter two digit number.
thirt four
Enter two digit number.
thirt five
Enter two digit number.
thirt six
Enter two digit number.
thirt seven
Enter two digit number.
thirt eight
Enter two digit number.
thirt nine
Enter two digit number.
fourt
Enter two digit number.
fourt one
Enter two digit number.
fourt two
Enter two digit number.
fourt three
Enter two digit number.
fourt four
Enter two digit number.
fourt five
Enter two digit number.
fourt six
Enter two digit number.
fourt seven
Enter two digit number.
fourt eight
Enter two digit number.
fourt nine
Enter two digit number.
fift
Enter two digit number.
fift one
Enter two digit number.
fift two
Enter two digit number.
fift three
Enter two digit number.
fift four
Enter two digit number.
fift five
Enter two digit number.
fift six
Enter two digit number.
fift seven
Enter two digit number.
fift eight
Enter two digit number.
fift nine
Enter two digit number.
sixt
Enter two digit number.
sixt one
Enter two digit number.
sixt two
Enter two digit number.
sixt three
Enter two digit number.
sixt four
Enter two digit number.
sixt five
Enter two digit number.
sixt six
Enter two digit number.
sixt seven
Enter two digit number.
sixt eight
Enter two digit number.
sixt nine
Enter two digit number.
sevent
Enter two digit number.
sevent one
Enter two digit number.
sevent two
Enter two digit number.
sevent three
Enter two digit number.
sevent four
Enter two digit number.
sevent five
Enter two digit number.
sevent six
Enter two digit number.
sevent seven
Enter two digit number.
sevent eight
Enter two digit number.
sevent nine
Enter two digit number.
eighty
Enter two digit number.
eighty one
Enter two digit number.
eighty two
Enter two digit number.
eighty three
Enter two digit number.
eighty four
Enter two digit number.
eighty five
Enter two digit number.
eighty six
Enter two digit number.
eighty seven
Enter two digit number.
eighty eight
Enter two digit number.
eighty nine
Enter two digit number.
ninety
Enter two digit number.
ninety one
Enter two digit number.
ninety two
Enter two digit number.
ninety three
Enter two digit number.
ninety four
Enter two digit number.
ninety five
Enter two digit number.
ninety six
Enter two digit number.
ninety seven
Enter two digit number.
ninety eight
Enter two digit number.
ninety nine
```

Comment: Yes, I misspelled thirty, forty, fifty, and sixty.  But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    int first_digit, second_digit;

    printf("Enter two digits: ");
    scanf("%1d%1d",&first_digit,&second_digit);


    switch(first_digit % 10) {
        case 1: {
                 switch(second_digit % 10) {
            case 0: printf(" ten"); break;
            case 1: printf(" eleven"); break;
            case 2: printf(" twelve"); break;
            case 3: printf(" thirteen"); break;
            case 4: printf(" fourteen"); break;
            case 5: printf(" fifteen"); break;
            case 6: printf(" sixteen"); break;
            case 7: printf(" seventeen"); break;
            case 8: printf(" eighteen"); break;
            case 9: printf(" ninteen"); break;
        }
        return 0;
        }
        case 2: printf("twenty"); break;
        case 3: printf("thirty"); break;
        case 4: printf("forty"); break;
        case 5: printf("fifty"); break;
        case 6: printf("sixty"); break;
        case 7: printf("seventy"); break;
        case 8: printf("eighty"); break;
        case 9: printf("ninety"); break;
    }
    switch(second_digit % 10) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: printf(" one"); break;
        case 2: printf(" two"); break;
        case 3: printf(" three"); break;
        case 4: printf(" four"); break;
        case 5: printf(" five"); break;
        case 6: printf(" six"); break;
        case 7: printf(" seven"); break;
        case 8: printf(" eight"); break;
        case 9: printf(" nine"); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```