# I am trying write a C program to print the string form for an integer.

Tags: c, string, integer

I am trying write a C program to print the string form for an integer. E.g 1234 -> one two three four. Is there a function that would convert it or would I make an array to do this?

Comment: You would have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

A simple recursive solution:

```
void print_number(unsigned x) {
  static const char *digit[10] = { 
          "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
          "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
  if (x >= 10) {
    print_number(x / 10);
    fputc(' ', stdout);
  }
  fputs(digit[x % 10], stdout);
}
```

Comment: The recursion avoids the need to either find out the number of digits (as my answer calculates) or to store partial output strings. Nice solution. +1.

Comment: @Will True that `fputc(' ', stdout)` is equivalent to `putchar(' ')`.  Since code uses `fputs(..., stdout)`, I find it more consistent to use `fputc(..., stdout)`, thus allowing a simple change to some other output stream.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you have a direct function to convert to text. But you can do something like this

C code to covert each digits of a number in English word

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  int number,i=0,j,digit;
  char * word[1000];

  printf("Enter any integer: ");
  scanf("%d",&number);

  while(number){

    digit = number %10;
    number = number /10;

      switch(digit){
         case 0: word[i++] = "zero"; break;
         case 1: word[i++] = "one"; break;
         case 2: word[i++] = "two"; break;
         case 3: word[i++] = "three"; break;
         case 4: word[i++] = "four"; break;
         case 5: word[i++] = "five"; break;
         case 6: word[i++] = "six"; break;
         case 7: word[i++] = "seven"; break;
         case 8: word[i++] = "eight"; break;
         case 9: word[i++] = "nine"; break;

       }
  }

  for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--){
     printf("%s ",word[j]);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Sample output:

Enter any integer: 23451208

two three four five one two zero eight

Also this is previously asked question. So refer to the link [Convert digit to text in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692586/converting-two-digit-number-to-words-using-switch-statement)

Comment: Nothing is printed when `number == 0`, expect "zero".

Answer (score -2):

There is no function to do this . You need to do it Manually .I am giving you the Code that will Help you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void check_print(int k);
int main()
{int n,i,m;

printf("Enter any  number");

Scanf("%d",&i);

n=i;

while(n!=0)
{

m=n%10;

check_print(m);

n=n/10;

}

}

void check_print(int k)
{
switch(k)
{

case 0:
printf("zero");
break;

case 1:
printf("one");
break;

case 2:
printf("two");
break;

case 3:
printf("Three");
break;

case 4:
printf("four");
break;

case 5:
printf("Five");
break;

case 6:
printf("Six");
break;

case 7:
printf("seven");
break;

case 8:
printf("Eight");
break;

case 9:
printf("nine"); 
break;

}

}
```

Comment: This code does `123` --> "Threetwoone", expect "one two three".  `0` --> ""  , expect "zero".

Comment: ohh Yup !...Maybe I...read it Wrong.

Comment: One more thing can be done here. just break the number in digits and save them in array .then reverse the array and pass each element of array to check_print() function. It will work