# How to convert numbers to words using basic commands in C

Tags: c

Hi I'm really new to C.
I am doing an exercise where I have to make a program that takes in two input integers (integers between -10 and 10 inclusive) and outputs the sum.
However, all the numbers from -10 to 10 inclusive that are displayed will be displayed as their respective words and any other number will be the numeric number.
The only commands I'm using are if's, else if's, else, printf, scanf, int.

An example is:

```
Enter your two integers: 9 2
nine + two = eleven

Enter your two integers: -9 4
negative nine + four = negative five

Enter your two integers: -10 -2
negative ten + negative two = -12
```

Any help is appreciated. Here is what I did so far but I'm not sure since it seems VERY tedious, but my friend said she did it relatively pretty fast.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int sum;
    printf("Please enter two integers: ");
    scanf("%d",&number1,&number2);
    sum = number1 + number2
    if (number1 > 0 && number2 > 0) {
        if (number1 == 1 && number2 == 1) {
            printf("one + one = two");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some stuff here. Not sure I particularly like the solutions though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692586/converting-two-digit-number-to-words-using-switch-statement

Comment: One or more arrays might be useful. The (absolute) numbers, or digits from them, could be used as indexes.

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` to read user input. The `*scanf()` function family is for reading known-well-formatted data from file, not potentially malformed user input. (For that, read a whole line with `fgets()` and parse in-memory with e.g. `strtol`). -- If you DO use `scanf()`, ALWAYS check its return value. If the user entered something other than integers, your variables are not initialized. -- You only read one integer (only one `%d` in your format string). Your `number2` is always undefined. -- Consider defining an array of words, and using the integers from the user as index into those arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It says not to use anything other than what's mentioned in the OP, so I don't think I can use arrays (I haven't learn this either)

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not sure what you mean by check its return value. How would I do this? Also, I haven't learnt arrays and I don't think I'm supposed to use anything other than what's mentioned in OP

Comment: Have you learned about `switch` or `if`? About division and modulo operators? About functions and how to return values from them? Use that then.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of items read successfully. You want to read two values, so if `scanf()` does not return `2`, something has gone wrong and you should abort the program. -- Have you learned `switch`? That would work as well.

Comment: you can do it in around 20 if statements if thats ok? you just check if number is negative, print a `-`, check numbers 0 through 20 and then print their respective words, wrap that in a function like `void printwordnum(int n)` and then call it 3 times for each number.

Comment: or if you can't use functions just copypaste the code 3 times :3

Comment: Thanks everyone, I haven't learnt switch yet though.

Comment: If they haven't shown you this already, I mean to `if ( scanf( ... ) == 2 ) { /* success, continue */ } else { /* insufficient input, abort */ }`. And they really *should* have taught you these things before setting you a problem that you have to solve with one hand tied behind your back...

Comment: @Theo Walton How would I "print their respective words"? Would I do something like 
if (&number1 == 1 && &number 2 == 1){
printf("one + one = two");
}
?  
(like I did in OP). Yeah I can't use functions.

Comment: why not make a table: `char *digits[] = {"zero","one","two" ...}`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I can't use 'char'

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot at least use functions? This assignment seems pretty pointless to me, unless the idea is to teach you how *not* to write computer programs.

Comment: only use &number1 in the ```scanf()``` function __"command"__. The __'&'__ character when used right before a variable name becomes the __address_of__ operator. If you have not learned functions, nor arrays I would find really absurd that you have learned pointers. Use ```if (number1 == 1 && number2 == 1)``` instead, like in the code on your question

Comment: @JennyT-Type Thank you for the comment. My instructor says we just use '&' in scanf() to tell the program to "store the input into these variables", it's the first time i've heard the term 'pointers' or 'address_of'. Does it screw up my code if I use two ampersands as I originally did?

Comment: @Groo Yeah, we can't use functions

Comment: @Taytayes using them inside the ```scanf()``` parenthesis is okay, like I said, the use of the '&' on your OP is actually okay. Sorry if I didn't express that clearly, About pointers, that is a more advanced topic, which you should encounter after you learn arrays.

Comment: @Taytayes: Generally speaking, and seconding Groo here, if you have *any* choice in the matter, find a different instructor. I am serious. This is a very, *very* poor way to introduce people to programming. He's making you jump through hoops that simply are not necessary once you've learned the mechanisms that would make this very, very easy. Which means you will have to *re-learn* things after the next lesson. This should never be done in teaching.

Answer (score 4):

> The only commands I'm using are if's, else if's, else, printf, scanf, int.

I agree with you that this looks pretty tedious.

The one point that I would like to make is that you can do each number individually - which will make it less tedious.

For example, modifying your code...  (*note this is not going to be compilable - just modified a bit to give a suggestion*)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int sum;
    int inputs;

    printf("Please enter two integers: ");

     // scanf replaced with new one including while
     // the first statement below will work provided the user provides the 
     // correct input data....
     //
     // scanf("%d %d",&number1,&number2); // added second %d - need two %d  one for each number
    //
    // would be better to this next scanf command below...
    // if scanf doesn't work due to bad input it will tell the user
    // while (scanf("%d %d",&number1,&number2) !=2) printf("incorrect input\nPlease enter two integers: "); 
    // but this uses 'while' which you haven't used yet if I understand correctly
    // 
    inputs = scanf("%d %d",&number1,&number2);
    if (inputs!=2) {
      printf("Incorrect input data\n"); 
      return 1;
    }
    // if scanf works inputs will have the value 2
    //
    // this if statement stops the program if inputs is not equal to 2
    // 
    sum = number1 + number2

    // the next bit suggested by Groo handles negative numbers nicely....
    if (number1 < 0) { 
      number1 = -number; printf("negative "); 
    }
    // if (number1 > 0 && number2 > 0) 
    if (number1 == 0) {
       printf("zero");
    }
    else if (number1 == 1) {
        printf("one");
    } else if (number1 == 2) {
      printf("two");
    } else if(number1 == 3) {
      printf("three");
    } else if(number1 == 4) {
      printf("four");
    } else if(number1 == 5) {
      printf("five");
    } else if(number1 == 6) {
      printf("six");
    } else if (number1 == 7) {
      printf("seven");
    } else if(number1 == 8) {
      printf("eight");
    } else if(number1 == 9) {
      printf("nine");
    } else if (number1 == 10) {
      printf("ten");
    } else  {
      printf("unknown number");
    } 
    printf(" + ");
     // now insert similar if statements to print number2 ....
      ....

  return 0;
```

}

hope this is a useful suggestion - if I had to do this I would be using arrays, which I guess you will learn about soon.

Comment: The assignment is completely ridiculous, but I believe OP can at least handle the "negative" part separately? I.e. `if (a < 0) { a = -a; printf("negative"); }`.

Comment: Using `scanf()` without checking return value.

Comment: @DevSolar I think, since the OP hasn't seen functions he wouldn't know about return values.

Comment: @JennyT-Type: No reason not to showcase proper use in an answer. Besides, *this* answer in particular *also* copy-pasted the error that it only ever reads *one* value, so it's UB no matter what the user enters...

Comment: @DevSolar Ops I missed that UB. ```scanf("%d",&number1,&number2);```dealing with other UB right now xD, do you think I should try and edit the answer?.

Comment: @tom we're on a race here!

Comment: @JennyT-Type  --- ahhh hmm... excuse me ? sorry don't understand

Comment: @DevSolar ok -- that edit is coming... (now I know what you mean about the race.. jenny)

Comment: @Groo - yes - I was wondering about just stopping the program if there was incorrect data input, but thought that might be too extreme.... but it is a good point and I will include it in the next edit....

Comment: @Groo like your comment at the top about negative numbers - will try to put that in now... and there is also zero of course.....

Answer (score 2):

The actual algorithm here is the easy part, simply declare an array of pointers to string literals and use that as look-up table:

```
const char* TEXTUAL [11] = 
{
  "zero",
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six",
  "seven",
  "eight",
  "nine",
  "ten"
};  

printf("%s", TEXTUAL[value]);
```

The hard part here is all the error checking. You have to read two integers from the user, check that they are valid and in range -10 to 10. Then check that the result is in range as well.

I made an example that you can look at for hints. How to safely read integers in C is a chapter of it's own, I made a function `read_2_int` that reads user input in a safe manner. If you are a beginner, just ignore that function for now and use `scanf("%d", &var)`.

In order to handle negative numbers I used the function `labs` to get the absolute value of an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static void halt_and_catch_fire (const char* err);
static void read_2_int (int* i1, int* i2);

int main (void)
{
  int n1;
  int n2;

  printf("Enter your two integers: ");
  read_2_int(&n1, &n2);


  if(n1 > 10 || n1 < -10 || n2 > 10 || n2 < -10)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire("Only numbers from -10 to 10 supported.");
  }
  if(n1+n2 > 10 || n1+n2 < -10)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire("The sum must be from -10 to 10.");
  }


  const char* TEXTUAL [11] = 
  {
    "zero",
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
    "ten"
  };  


  if(n1 < 0){ printf("minus "); }
  printf("%s + ", TEXTUAL[labs(n1)] ); // labs = absolute value
  if(n2 < 0){ printf("minus "); }
  printf("%s = ", TEXTUAL[labs(n2)] );
  if(n1 + n2 < 0) { printf("minus "); }
  printf("%s\n", TEXTUAL[labs(n1+n2)] );
}


static void halt_and_catch_fire (const char* err)
{
  /* some manner of error handling here */
  fprintf(stderr, err);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void read_2_int (int* i1, int* i2)
{
  char input[10];

  if(fgets(input, 10, stdin) == NULL)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire ("You have to type two integers.");
  }

  char* endptr;
  *i1 = strtol(input, &endptr, 10);
  if(endptr == input)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire ("Bad number format");
  }

  char* next = endptr;
  *i2 = strtol(next, &endptr, 10);
  if(endptr == next)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire ("You have to type two integers.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code find useful:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int sum;
    char *digits[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
                       "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};

    printf("Please enter two integers: ");
    scanf("%d",&number1);
    scanf("%d",&number2);
    sum = number1 + number2;

    if(number1<0){
        printf("negative ");
        number1=-number1;
    }
    printf("%s",digits[number1]);
    printf(" + ");

    if(number2<0){
        printf("negative ");
        number2=-number2;
    }
    printf("%s",digits[number2]);
    printf(" = ");
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Comment: can you try to explain how you come up with this solution?

Comment: The size of `digits[]` needn't be 20. Maybe it's better not to specify the size. Let the compiler figure it out. And you haven't provided a string for 10.

Comment: I created array named digits that store string representation of numbers.And i used number1 and number2 as index of array to print output.

Comment: @DevSolar i cannot understand "using scanf() without checking return value"?can you please explain this?

Comment: @J...S Thank you for your feedback.I edited my code.I provided a string for 10.

Comment: @KarthikaKavi: Ask yourself what happens (or, rather, what does *not* happen) with `number1` and `number2` if the user enters something that is *not* a number, but, say, "foo"... and how you could avoid that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a program which works for all numbers from 0 upto 99,999.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
int n,i;
int rem,r2,k=0;
char *word[100000];
char *word_temp[100000];
char *units[]={" zero"," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine"};
char *teens[]={" ten"," eleven"," twelve"," thirteen"," fourteen"," fifteen"," sixteen"," seventeen"," eighteen"," nineteen"};
char *tenths[]={" twenty"," thirty"," forty"," fifty"," sixty"," seventy"," eighty"," ninety"};
char *hundredth[]={" hundred"};
char *thousandth[]={" thousand"};
printf("\nenter the number(only positive and less than one lakh): ");
scanf("%d",&n);

if(n==0){
    word[k++]=units[0];

    printf("\nthe number in words: ");
    for(i=(k-1);i>=0;i--)
        printf("%s",word[i]);
}

else if(n>0&&n<=99999){
    while(n>0) {
        word_temp[k]="";

        if((n>999)&&(n<=99999)){
            rem=n/1000;

            if((rem>19)&&(rem<=99)){
                if((rem%10)!=0){
                    word_temp[++k]=units[rem%10];
                    word[k]=word_temp[k];
                    k--;
                }
                word_temp[k]=tenths[(rem/10)-2];
                word[k]=word_temp[k];
                if((rem%10)!=0)
                    k+=2;
                else
                    k++;
            }

            else {
                if(rem<10)
                    word_temp[k]=units[rem];

                else if(rem>9&&rem<20)
                    word_temp[k]=teens[rem%10];  
                    word[k]=word_temp[k];
                    k++;
            }
            word_temp[k]=thousandth[0];
            word[k]=word_temp[k];
            k++;
            n=n-(rem*1000);
        }

        else if((n>99)&&(n<=999)){
            rem=n/100;
            word_temp[k]=units[rem];
            word[k]=word_temp[k];
            k++;
            word_temp[k]=hundredth[0];
            word[k]=word_temp[k];
            k++;
            word[k++]=" and";
            n=n-(rem*100);
        }

        else if((n>19)&&(n<=99)){
            rem=n/10;
            word_temp[k]=tenths[rem-2];
            word[k]=word_temp[k];
            k++;
            n=n-(rem*10);
        }

        else if((n>9)&&(n<=19)){
            rem=n;
            word_temp[k]=teens[rem%10];
            word[k]=word_temp[k];
            k++;
            n=n-(rem*1);
            break;
        }

        else if((n>0)&&(n<=9)){
            rem=n%10;
            word_temp[k]=units[rem];
            word[k]=word_temp[k];
            k++;
            n=0;
            break;
        }

    }

    printf("\nthe number in words:\n ");
    for(i=0;i<=k-1;i++)
        printf("%s ",word[i]);
    }
    else {
         printf("\nvalue out of range...Exiting...");
         exit(0);
    }

    printf("\n\nprocess terminated... ");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to do an auxiliary function

```
void numberName(int number){

  if (number < 0){
      printf("negative ");
      number=number*(-1);
  }
  if(number == 0){
      printf("zero");
  }else if (number == 1){
      printf("one");
  }else if (number == 2){
      printf("two");
  }else if (number == 3){
      printf("three");
  }else if (number == 4){
      printf("four");
  }else if (number == 5){
      printf("five");
  }else if (number == 6){
      printf("six");
  }else if (number == 7){
      printf("seven");
  }else if (number == 8){
      printf("eight");
  }else if (number == 9){
      printf("nine");
  }else if (number == 10){
      printf("ten");
  }
}
```

and in your main() code call this function like this:

```
numberName(number1);
printf(" + ");
numberName(number2);
printf(" = ");
numberName(sum);
printf("\n");
```

By the way, watch your code, the scan function should be:

```
scanf("%d%d",&number1,&number2);
```

Comment: Using `scanf()` without checking return value.

Comment: This is nonsense, use arrays.